# Dynamically change a type with C#

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am very new to C# and ServiceStack and I am working on a small project that consists on calling a third party API and loading the data I get back from the API into a relational database via ServiceStack's ORMLite.

The idea is to have each endpoint of the API have a reusable model that determines how it should be received in the API's response, and how it should be inserted into the database.

So I have something like the following:

```
    [Route("/api/{ApiEndpoint}", "POST")]
    public class ApiRequest : IReturn<ApiResponse>
    {
        public Int32 OrderId { get; set; }
        public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
        public String ApiEndpoint { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApiResponse
    {
        public Endpoint1[] Data { get; set; }
        public String ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public Int32 ErrorNumber { get; set; }
        public String ErrorDesc { get; set; }
    }

    public class Endpoint1
    {
        [AutoIncrement] 
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        [CustomField("DATETIME2(7)")]
        public String PurchaseDate { get; set; }

        [CustomField("NVARCHAR(50)")]
        public String Customer { get; set; }

        [CustomField("NVARCHAR(20)")]
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public Int32 Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

My first class represents the API's request with its route, the second class represents the API's response. The API's response is the same for all endpoints, but the only thing that varies is the structure of the `Data` field that comes back from that endpoint. I've defined the structure of one of my endpoints in my `Endpoint1` class, and I am using it in my API's response class. As you can see, I am also defining a few attributes on my `Endpoint1` class to help the ORM make better decisions later when inserting the data.

Ok, so the issue is that I have about 15 endpoints and I don't want to create 15 `ApiResponse` classes when I know the only thing that changes is that first `Data` field in the class.

So I made something like this:

```
public class DataModels
    {
        public Type getModel(String endpoint)
        {
            Dictionary<String, Type> models = new Dictionary<String, Type>();

            models.Add("Endpoint1", typeof(Endpoint1));
            // models.Add("Endpoint2", typeof(Endpoint2));
            // models.Add("Endpoint3", typeof(Endpoint3));
            // and so forth...

            return models[endpoint];  
        }

    }
```

I would like for `getModel()` to be called when the request is made so that I can pass in the `ApiEndpoint` field in the `ApiRequest` class and store the type that I want my `Data` field to have so that I can dynamically change it in my `ApiResponse` class.

In addition, there is the ORM part where I iterate over every endpoint and create a different table using the model/type of each endpoint. Something like this:

```
endpoints.ForEach(
       (endpoint) =>
            {
                db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Endpoint1>();
                // inserting data, doing other work etc
            }
);
```

But again, I'd like to be able to call `getModel()` in here and with that define the model of the specific endpoint I am iterating on.

I've attempted calling `getModel()` on both places but I always get errors back like `cannot use variable as a type`and others... so I am definitely doing something wrong.

Feel free to suggest a different approach to `getModel()`. This is just what I came up with but I might be ignoring a much simpler approach.

Answer (score 3):

When I DID understand you correctly, you have different API-Calls which all return the same object. The only difference is, that the field "`Data`" can have different types.

Then you can simply change the type of data to object:

```
public object Data { get; set; }
```

And later simply cast this to the required object:

```
var data1=(Endpoint1[]) response.Data;
```

Comment: well the challenge is that I would like to cast the type in a dynamic manner. So I don't want to manually write `var data1=(Endpoint1[])` but instead something like `var data1=(getModel(endpoint)[])` where the argument in the method `endpoint` contains the name of the endpoint as a string and returns the appropriate type for that endpoint. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jgozal: What you want is not idiomatic for C#. You're also trying to violate the reason we have type safety in the first place: developers want compile-time errors instead of runtime errors. There are many other ways to solve the problem (e.g. generics) that do not involve trying to go around type safety rules.

Comment: @jgozal that seems a little contrived

Comment: Please have some pity on me. I come from a JavaScript background where literally everything is possible so I'm trying to understand how to do things in C# without being too verbose at the same time. How do you then suggest I go about this? Am I just supposed to write 15 ApiResponse classes with different Data types?

Comment: @jgozal: Don't write 15 copy/paste classes. Have a look at C# generics instead. (I'd give you the Google link but for some reason Google is blocked at work today :-/)

Comment: @Flater a potential issue that I see with generics like `Hashtable` (which would work fine in the response) is that I can't define the custom attributes I'm defining to help the ORM make better decisions about the datatypes in the table, so my table will be full of varchar(max)

Comment: Ah I guess `Hashtable` is not even a generic?

Comment: @jgozal You're on the wrong track. You need to stop trying to change variable types at runtime, because it's not going to work or do you any favors. Simply make a generic DTO class like this: `public class MyGenericDtoClass<T> { public T MyData { get; set; } }` and then you can do things like `return new MyGenericDtoClass<Endpoint1>();` The generic type you supply (`<Endpoint1>`) declares the type of the inner `MyData` property.

Comment: @Flater if you have the time could you write a more detailed response on that idea explaining how I would incorporate it in the rest of my code?

Comment: @jgozal: Without trying to offend; part of the issue here is that you're not aware of C#-idiomatic approaches and how to implement them. You need to brush up on these; and explaning C# basics is well out of scope for an answer on StackOverflow. For the current issue, reading up on how to create generic classes should give you the necessary knowledge to tackle this problem.

Comment: @Flater not offended. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @Flater - something that still remains even when using generic types is that I need to write a separate line for each template I pass into the generic type like  `MyGenericDtoClass<Endpoint1>();` , `MyGenericDtoClass<Endpoint2>();`, `MyGenericDtoClass<Endpoint3>();`. It's kind of the same problem all over. There is really no way to change the template of the generic type based on a specific situation dynamically with something simple like a dictionary? I'm going to have to write a huge switch in my loop if not

Comment: @jgozal: The problem is the same, because you keep trying to implement the same type of solution. C# has no variable types. Things like `var myObject` may _look like_ they offer freely changeable types, but this code still only compiles if the actual type (instead of `var`) is known **at compile-time**. If you're looking to avoid separate-but-similar code; then you need to look at either _inheritance_ or _interfaces_, to have all `Endpoint` classes share a common logical approach. But again, you need to accept that you can't use type declarations like you do in Javascript.

Comment: To be honest there is the "dynamic" type which behaves like JavaScript car but you should never use it

Comment: I ended up doing a mixture of using a generic class and casting the object Data in different parts of the app depending on the endpoint

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a very tough time trying to dynamically create .NET types dynamically which requires advanced usage of Reflection.Emit. It's self-defeating trying to dynamically create Request DTOs with ServiceStack since the client and metadata services needs the concrete Types to be able to call the Service with a Typed API.

I can't really follow your example but my initial approach would be whether you can use a single Service (i.e. instead of trying to dynamically create multiple of them). Likewise with OrmLite if the Schema of the POCOs is the same, it sounds like you would be able to flatten your DataModel and use a single database table.

AutoQuery is an [example of a feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#getting-started) which [dynamically creates Service Implementations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/657e7ab5e78210bdd2f25084c965e4da5c4394e3/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs#L211) from just a concrete Request DTO, which is effectively the minimum Type you need.

So whilst it's [highly recommended to have explict DTOs for each Service](http://docs.servicestack.net/why-remote-services-use-dtos) you can use inheritance to reuse the common properties, e.g:

```
[Route("/api/{ApiEndpoint}/1", "POST")]
public ApiRequest1 : ApiRequestBase<Endpoint1> {}

[Route("/api/{ApiEndpoint}/2", "POST")]
public ApiRequest2 : ApiRequestBase<Endpoint1> {}

public abstract class ApiRequestBase<T> : IReturn<ApiResponse<T>>
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string ApiEndpoint { get; set; }
}
```

And your Services can return the same generic Response DTO:

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public T[] Data { get; set; }
    public String ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public Int32 ErrorNumber { get; set; }
    public String ErrorDesc { get; set; }
}
```

I can't really understand the purpose of what you're trying to do so the API design is going to need modifications to suit your use-case.

You're going to have similar issues with OrmLite which is a Typed code-first POCO ORM where you're going to run into friction trying to use dynamic types which don't exist at Runtime where you'll likely have an easier time [executing Dynamic SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#custom-insert-and-updates) since it's far easier to generate a string than a .NET Type.

With that said [GenericTableExpressions.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/Expression/GenericTableExpressions.cs) shows an example of changing the Table Name that OrmLite saves a POCO to at runtime:

```
const string tableName = "Entity1";
using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<GenericEntity>(tableName);

    db.Insert(tableName, new GenericEntity { Id = 1, ColumnA = "A" });

    var rows = db.Select(tableName, db.From<GenericEntity>()
        .Where(x => x.ColumnA == "A"));

    Assert.That(rows.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));

    db.Update(tableName, new GenericEntity { ColumnA = "B" },
        where: q => q.ColumnA == "A");

    rows = db.Select(tableName, db.From<GenericEntity>()
        .Where(x => x.ColumnA == "B"));

    Assert.That(rows.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Which uses these extension methods:

```
public static class GenericTableExtensions
{
    static object ExecWithAlias<T>(string table, Func<object> fn)
    {
        var modelDef = typeof(T).GetModelMetadata();
        lock (modelDef)
        {
            var hold = modelDef.Alias;
            try
            {
                modelDef.Alias = table;
                return fn();
            }
            finally
            {
                modelDef.Alias = hold;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DropAndCreateTable<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table)
    {
        ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => { 
            db.DropAndCreateTable<T>();
            return null;
        });
    }

    public static long Insert<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table, T obj, bool selectIdentity = false)
    {
        return (long)ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => db.Insert(obj, selectIdentity));
    }

    public static List<T> Select<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table, SqlExpression<T> expression)
    {
        return (List<T>)ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => db.Select(expression));
    }

    public static int Update<T>(this IDbConnection db, string table, T item, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return (int)ExecWithAlias<T>(table, () => db.Update(item, where));
    }
}
```

But it's not an approach I'd take personally, if I absolutely needed (and I'm struggling to think of a valid use-case outside of table-based Multitenancy or sharding) to save the same schema in multiple tables I'd just be using inheritance again, e.g:

```
public class Table1 : TableBase {}
public class Table2 : TableBase {}
public class Table3 : TableBase {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to take a few minutes to digest it but I'll say that my tables do not have the same schema, hence why I'm trying to dynamically change the type in `db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Endpoint1>();`. The table name is not so important but rather the columns that I am creating from using that type

Comment: @jgozal If they don't have the same schema then you should be creating different Data Models to capture the schema? I'm not seeing the benefit of using Reflection.Emit to dynamically create Types at runtime when C# has a perfectly good DSL for describing a Type with auto properties.

Comment: Oh I am creating different Data Models. `Endpoint1` is one of them. But I'm still trying to figure out how to switch between them when I create my tables and when I call the third party API if that makes sense

Comment: @jgozal: Reading between the lines here; I think your experience in Javascript has led you to be quite cheeky about changing the type of a given variable at runtime. While Javascript allows for things like that; it's never a good idea (in the interest of readability and reducing complexity). C# specifically tries to prevent this from happening by enforcing type safety. Instead of trying to find a way around C#'s type safety; I advise you instead learn how to work _with_ it, as it will dramatically improve your code readability as well as provide you with compile-time safety.

Comment: @Flater whether it is a good idea or not, this is something we do all the time in production code when working with JS (dynamically changing things in run-time). I'm not sure why this is so dangerous. You are just taking decisions like you would do with a simple conditional (eg. if the endpoint is x, return the type of x). I'm not trying to push for this approach in C#, I understand from the comments that it is not how it's done. But in any case I don't understand why the approach is dangerous at all.

Comment: @jgozal It's not particularly _dangerous_, it just complicates the code and hinders future development. It makes it harder to spot what is going on and makes it possible for developer error to creep in (e.g. returning the wrong object, since nothing is stopping you from passing an value of a different type). It works, and it can be done correctly with no mistakes; but it does make it easier to _make_ a mistake. That's all :)

Comment: @Flater haha all of what you say is so natural to me that I just think of it as my day to day natural development process. I'll brush of on generics and see how I can take advantage of the answers here.